# What should happen to an impossible cube at a vertex?

Tags: geometry, 3d

I have automated the process of impossible-cube renders in Blender3D as an exercise. However, while the automator works fine as long as the intersection of the 'impossible' edge and the nearer edge is as per the image below, I'm unsure how to proceed when the impossible edge passes 'in front of' the vertex (where the animation below stops).

Is there mathematically defined behavior for such an impossible shape, or is it up to artistic license?

[image: Impossible Cube Animation]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't imagine a proper way to render it, in a similar way to how  you've done it. I suggest going back to a still isometric image of the cube, and colouring each direction of face a specific colour. Any joined up colour you then must treat as flat. Then after a lot of trial and error, something will begin.